# Putting files in emulator external storage, prior to app starting

Tags: android, android-emulator

Using the emulator, with external storage attached, I would like to emulate what happens when the application starts up and certain files are already present in the relevant directory on ext storage.

Is the external storage actually located on my machine, after enabling it in the AVD? Or should I be creating the files with some temporary, throw away code? Or should I just test on a real device?

What is best practice for this scenario?

Comment: I can't get it the following solution. It seem location has changed. Get it from `mnt/sdcard` from DDMS perspective of Eclipse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `sdcard.img` is in the avd folder (`~/.android/avd`). If you are using Linux or OSX you can mount it, manipulate the files inside, and unmount it.
Probably there's a program in Windows that let you do the same.
As an alternative, you can start the emulator and then manipulate the sdcard content using `adb push/pull` or `DDMS`.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way of creating the `SDCard` contents, would be to create the files that you need on your machine and then using the `DDMS Perspective` in `Eclipse` you can select your `emulator` in the `Devices` panel on the left, and then choose the `FileExplorer` tab on the right. There is a folder named `sdcard` which contains the `SDCard` contents.

By using the controlls on the right upper-side you can create folders inside the `SDCard` and by you can also `Push` files on the `emulators` `SDCard`.

As @dtmilano said, you can also achieve the same thing using `Command Prompt`.